# Как правильно тянуть зависимости (Ninject)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

Добрый день
При попытке связать SignalR и Ninject возникла проблема с подтягиванием зависимостей, в классе хаба, то есть если я пытаюсь вытащить класс не использующий DI то все нормально, но при попытке вытащить класс, который сам через конструктор пытается подтянуть зависимость то, не получается ничего.
Вот так я пытаюсь вытащить

```
    private IDirectory<IEventSourceApplicationModel> _repo;
    private IEventSourceApplicationService<IEventSourceApplicationModel> _eventSourceApplicationService;
    public AdminHub(IDirectory<IEventSourceApplicationModel> repo,
        IEventSourceApplicationService<IEventSourceApplicationModel> eventSourceApplicationService)
    {
        _repo = repo;
        _eventSourceApplicationService = eventSourceApplicationService;
    }
    public AdminHub()
        : this((IDirectory<IEventSourceApplicationModel>)NinjectWebCommon.resolver.GetService(typeof(IDirectory<IEventSourceApplicationModel>)),
              (IEventSourceApplicationService<IEventSourceApplicationModel>)NinjectWebCommon.resolver.GetService(typeof(IEventSourceApplicationService<IEventSourceApplicationModel>)))
    { }
```

В случае с IDirectory все нормально так как он в себе не содержит DI 
но в случае с IEventSourceApplicationService не работает так как он в себе подтягивает через DI другую директорию